# grep multiple search patterns from piped input and report individual counts incrementally

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

There's some output spewed from tests which has pattern "PASSED", "FAILED", "CRASHED", I want to be able to see incremental output on the screen as tests progress with their counts

```
run_tests | <grep or some command that does counting>
PASSED 1 FAILED 0 CRASHED 0
.. after running 25 tests
PASSED 20 FAILED 5 CRASHED 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{passed = 0; failed = 0; crashed=0}
/PASSED/{passed++} /FAILED/{failed++} /CRASHED/{crashed++}  
{print "PASSED " passed " FAILED " failed " CRASHED " crashed}'
```